# Is the US government preparing to remove religiosity in the population with a virus, using vaccines as a vector?

Tags: united-states, government, virus

This Vimeo video ["
DOD VIRUS 'FUNVAX' Vaccine for RELIGIOUS Peoples!!!!!!!"](http://vimeo.com/74080203) purports to show a government presentation about the deliberate introduction of a virus.

> Leaked April 13, 2005 video shows how the Pentagon intends to destroy people’s brains by putting a virus in vaccines used by most of the population.
>
> The virus will act to eliminate the sense of ‘fundamentalism’ from people in war zones such as Afghanistan. The elimination of the so-called God Gene would be achieved by putting the virus in a vaccine that is widely provided to a population, which would ensure a larger reach.
>
> As if disease alone wasn’t a problem, there are powerful people searching for ways to change the way people think and act. A video apparently originated in the Department of Defense (DoD), which is identified with the number 149AZ2 and recorded in room BC282 of the Pentagon shows a speaker relating to a rather small audience the breakthrough in the making of a brain eating virus which will make people permanently passive, by attacking the V-Mat 2 gene.

Is this video staged?

Comment: Is there any indication that the claim is NOTABLE? (e.g. video view counter showing something above 3 digits)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This was debunked by Mick West at [*Debunked: FunVax, Pentagon Briefing on Removing the God Gene*](http://www.metabunk.org/threads/debunked-funvax-pentagon-briefing-on-removing-the-god-gene.317/)

The image in the video at [2:01](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRg41D8SOq0&t=121) (left, labelled "A") uses the same brain MRI as an image in a December 2010 article in *Neurology*, "[*A case of confusion and bilateral temporal lesions in a young woman*](http://www.neurology.org/content/75/18_Supplement_1/S67.full.pdf+html)" (right, labelled "B").

[image]
[image]

The video claims to be from April 13, 2005. But, the image did not exist until 2010.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks.